# Find unmatched data in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this 2 simple tables
[image]

I want to select unmatching data from SAMPLE1 by comparing FruitName in SAMPLE2
So far I have tried

```
SELECT * FROM SAMPLE1,SAMPLE2 WHERE SAMPLE1.FruitName NOT LIKE '%' + dbo.SAMPLE2.FruitName +'%'
```

But this gives me total 7 records
[image]
What I want the output is
[image]

Comment: You also have to match the ID fields, otherwise it will match every record with every other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM SAMPLE1 s1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT NULL
        FROM SAMPLE2 s2
        WHERE s1.FruitName LIKE '%' + s2.FruitName + '%'
        )
```

Comment: Ohh Thank you so much I was trying hard but no luck, but with your query it worked like a charm Thank you so much. God bless you

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM SAMPLE1,SAMPLE2 WHERE SAMPLE1.FruitName NOT LIKE '%' + dbo.SAMPLE2.FruitName +'%' AND SAMPLE1.id = SAMPLE2.id
```

Have to make sure you're comparing equal IDs.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe that help:

```
select SAMPLE1.* from SAMPLE1
 Left join SAMPLE2 ON SAMPLE1.fruitName LIKE concat('%', SAMPLE2.fruitName, '%')
Where SAMPLE2.id is null
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5269ac/11/0)